# how to insert the excel sheet into database and how to retrieve the excel data from it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

hi i want to insert the excel sheet into database,and retreive the excel sheet data.i want to insert the excel sheet in so many times with new header columns,means for 1st time i want to insert one excel sheet with columns as jan11,feb11,marc11.for 2nd time i want inert the excel sheet having the columns as jan12,feb12,mar12,for 3rd time jan13,feb13,mar13,........etc,.for this what shoul i do?actually i tried this,but am gettiing some other.i did like as foloows....

1)created table with same columns,which is excel sheet have

2)uploaded that excel sheet into table

3)retrieved that data from table

but i dont want like this beacause,when i insert the new excel sheet into database,i want to delete the existing excel sheet,and replace that with new excel sheet,how it is possible ?can any one please help me

Comment: you can directly place the file into database using BLOB datatype.

Comment: You can use SqlServer Import/Export Data feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party library excellibrary which contains many inbuilt functions for manipulation of workbooks and worksheets. Kindly refer following link:

https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement **SSIS task** to solve your purpose.

In that,to delete existing data you can have a **Execute SQL task** in which you write delete command (For e.g. delete from ExcelTableName) which will delete all rows from table before inserting new data from excel.

Refer: [Export data to Excel file using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109622/export-data-to-excel-file-using-ssis)

Refer below link for moving Data From Excel to SQL Server:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server---10-steps-to-follow/